# How to trigger action when going to sleep using Task Scheduler for Win Vista

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, task, sleep, scheduler

I need to kill a program before going to sleep. I created .bat file killing the process and I would like to trigger it with Task Scheduler. I have found forum where guy achieved it somehow. Unfortnately I cannot find such a trigger. Is something like this possible?

EDIT: I've been able to set it (on workspace lock). Problem is that it is called on login (too late). Task is not done before going to sleep or set off before connecting to the internet (which is what I need)

Comment: taskkill /f /im "file.exe" -> that part works